# SQL - SELECT max(someDate) and another field -> returning something incoherent

Tags: sql, select

I have a table called myTable which is like this:

```
id, myDate, name, group  
1, 2012-04-09, john, subGroup-A  
2, 2012-04-10, marc, subGroup-B
```

I would like to retrieve the record with the maxDate and the name that goes with it, for the subGroup that starts with 'subGroup'. So I am doing the following query:

```
SELECT max(myDate) AS maxDate, name FROM myTable WHERE group LIKE "subGroup%";
```

I would expect this query to return me this:

```
maxDate, name  
2012-04-10, marc
```

But instead it is returning me this:

```
maxDate, name  
2012-04-10, john
```

So basically the maxDate is taken correctly, but the name is not the one corresponding to that date. I really do not get it. Hope someone can help me understand. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is:

```
 SELECT max(myDate) AS maxDate, name FROM myTable WHERE group LIKE "subGroup%";
```

I think you need the following:

```
SELECT MAX(myDate) AS maxDate, name 
FROM  myTable 
GROUP BY NAME 
HAVING group LIKE "subGroup%"
```

or

```
SELECT myDate AS maxDate, name 
FROM myTable 
WHERE group LIKE "subGroup%" AND myDate = (SELECT MAX(myDate) FROM myTable)
```

Comment: Your query even can't be executed as group by is missing?

Comment: Hello levanlevi. Thanks! Your input helped me understand and find a "light" workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this post [I need a sql query to group by name but return other fields based on the most recent entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079013/i-need-a-sql-query-to-group-by-name-but-return-other-fields-based-on-the-most-re/10079155#10079155) 
There are 2 solutions for MSSQL and one universal.

And the main rule: never include to `SELECT` list columns that aren't included into `GROUP BY` clause or have aggregate function.

Comment: Hello Andrey, thanks for trying to help. Before considering a "heavy" work around I am curious to understand why my select query is returning me that weird result. Is it a normal behavior according to you?

Comment: Hi Mark. I think my post is clear enough. Your task is to find row that contains tha MAX date. It is not the same as grouping. And as I mentioned before, it is VERY bad idea to include non-grouping fields into SELECT list. In this way your query will return ANY row. I believe you use mysql. This query will cause an error in other RDBMS.